# Twig, truncating text and PHP error

Tags: php, twig

I have a small simple Twig site (no Symfony install, so config.yml is not relevant here) and this is my code:

.htaccess file:

```
php_flag display_startup_errors on
php_flag display_errors on
php_flag html_errors on
```

employees.html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
      }        
      tr.heading {      
        font-weight: bolder;
      }        
      td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 0 0.5em;
      }    
    </style>  
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>Employees</h2>
    <table>
      <tr class="heading">
      </tr> 
      {% for d in data %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{ d.name|escape }}</td>
        <td>{{ d.role|escape }}</td>
        <td>{{ d.salary|escape }}</td>
      </tr> 
      {% endfor %}
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Employees is varchar(255), role is varchar(255) in MySQL.

and my code:

```
<?php
// include and register Twig auto-loader
include 'Twig/Autoloader.php';
Twig_Autoloader::register();

// attempt a connection
try {
  $dbh = new PDO('mysql:dbname=employedb1;host=localhost', 'test', 'test');
} catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo "Error: Could not connect. " . $e->getMessage();
}

// set error mode
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

// attempt some queries
try {
  // execute SELECT query
  // store each row as an object
  $sql = "SELECT name, role, salary FROM employees";
  $sth = $dbh->query($sql);
  while ($row = $sth->fetchObject()) {
    $data[] = $row;
  }

  // close connection, clean up
  unset($dbh); 

  // define template directory location
  $loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('templates');

  // initialize Twig environment
  $twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);

  // load template
  $template = $twig->loadTemplate('employees.html');

  // set template variables
  // render template
  echo $template->render(array (
    'data' => $data
  ));

} catch (Exception $e) {
  die ('ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage());
}
?>
```

It worked until I made the following modification to index.php (comment added above twig extension, not actually in original code):
http://pastebin.com/QMaQXEip

It worked until I added the Text extension, and generated this error:
Fatal error: Class 'Twig_Extensions_Extension_Text' not found in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/employtesttwig/index.php on line 34 (line 34 referring to Twig_Extensions_Extension_Text() above).

Why is this happening and how can I resolve this error?

Thanks.

Comment: Well, do you have that class?

Answer (score 0):

As you say, you just use Twig in your custom setup.
I guess you have to add Twig-extensions, which can be found here:
https://github.com/fabpot/Twig-extensions

The class which is missing: `Twig_Extensions_Extension_Text` is part of the Twig-Extensions lib and not of the Twig core.

Did you download the package and included or autoloaded the necessary files?

To cite the docs:

> Of course, you need to first load the extension file by either using
>   require_once() or by using an autoloader (see
>   spl_autoload_register()).